# How to validate form and then issue a post http request jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to validate my form. For example, when a user did not enter any value or white spaces, the **jQuery validation plugin** will detect the error and display an error message called, "please fill in the field" or "no white space". If the validation is correct, a post HTTP request will be issued with the help of jQuery ajax to send the information to the server. Currently, I am able to validate but unable to issue the post HTTP request when the user clicks submit. Here are my codes

```js
<script>

    function WebFormData(inLessonName) {

        this.lessonName = inLessonName;
    }

    $('#dataForm').validate({

        rules: {
            lessonName: {
                required: true,
                nowhitespace: true
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {

            var collectedLessonName = $('#lessonName').val();

            var webFormData = new WebFormData(collectedLessonName);
            var webFormDataInString = JSON.stringify(webFormData);

            $saveSessionSynopsisDataHandler = $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/API/Session',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                data: "'" + webFormDataInString + "'"
            });
        }
    });


</script>
```

```html
<form id="dataForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <label class="control-label  col-md-4" for="lessonName">lesson name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lessonName" name="lessonName" class="form-control font-bold"
           maxlength="100" placeholder="lessonName" value="" />

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
       
            </div>
        </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Could you try and change your type="button" to type="submit"? I've seen it happen a lot that the submit handler event doesn't get triggered because of this. Also if I remember correct it's type:"POST" not method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onsubmit` method for `form` that calls a function. If it returns `false` then it doesn't submit, if `true`, the form submits. Just addapt my exemple with your jquery

```js
function validation(){
  // check whatever you want to check here, return false if there is an error like white space
  if (document.getElementById("name").value.length < 1) {
    window.alert("fill the field");
    return false; // form not submited
  } else {
    // if everything is fine then you can submit
    return true;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```